# Generating some real bad images on R

Tags: r, image, plot, r-corrplot

I'm messing around with package `corrplot` on R but somehow the image outputs are really messed up. The code is as simple as follows:

```
x_reprod <- data.frame(rnorm(100), runif(100), rgamma(100,1,1), rbeta(100,1,1))
M <- cor(x_reprod)
corrplot(M, type = 'upper', method = 'circle', number.cex = 'black', 
     title = 'Correlação entre Variáveis do Modelo', tl.cex = 1 )
```

[image: Here's what came as result]

Tried changing 'res' on png() to values higher than 300 command and all of that good stuff, but nothing changed. Tried to embed the image but the forum says I'm not allow yet.

EDIT: Karolis helped me adjusting margins, and that's is great, adding `mar()` argument on the code. The main issue I found here is the resolution. Mine is really "noisy", with flaws on the blue circle on the main diagonal, while the one ploted by Karolis is really fine, with better contrast between all the observations.

Comment: Putted res = 300.

Comment: I edited, hope it's better. And yes, you are absolutely right. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: You didn't include your call to `png()` in your update, which is otherwise very helpful.  I suspect the problem is in its parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue of margins (`mar`) within the `corrplot` itself. Luckily you can pass `mar` as an argument and change it:

```
x_reprod <- data.frame(rnorm(100), runif(100), rgamma(100,1,1), rbeta(100,1,1))
M <- cor(x_reprod)

corrplot(M, type = 'upper', method = 'circle', number.cex = 'black',
         title = 'Correlação entre Variáveis do Modelo', tl.cex = 1, mar=c(1,1,2,1))
```

And the result:

[image: corrplot]

Comment: Yeah, that's sure an issue and I'm glad for your answer, but there is something else. Your plot resolution is finer than mine. There is no flaws on the blue circles and you can actually see the other correlation circles. That's what's really bugging me.